# Ctrl+z not working 2.82?

Tags: shortcut

Undo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) not working in 2.82. In the keymap it shows, but it's not working. Is there any setting I need to change?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's still the same shortcut. Perhaps you've accidentally modified your keymap?

Comment: @RobertGützkow i pressed f3 and search undo and its same key and press the search undo still did not work?

Comment: Check that your undo steps aren't zero in *Edit > Preferences > System > Memory & Limits*.

Comment: @RobertGützkow i set both 32 memory limits and undo. I tried to change memory limit to 0 also nothing solved